# keep listview adapter text on master-detail flow select

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a master-detail flow which includes the names of online users and a the chat between those separate users. I want to be able to remember the chats (in the listview) for a given user so that when I go from selecting the one user to coming back to the other user, the information that was in that specific listview is still there.

Is there anyway to remember and keep a listview's text somewhere so that when I come back to that listview it can be recalled?

PLEASE! Someone help me because I've been sitting with this problem all day!

Comment: Create a DataModel class. Hold all data in that

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how would I create a data model class and where would I store it?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a Bean Class to hold your required data :

```
public class UserData()
{
     // You can add required data like name, image etc
     public String user_name;

     public UserData(String name)
     {
         user_name= name;
     }

}
```

**2.** Then when you get the data to load in the ListView, add them in the Model Class Object

```
ArrayList<UserData> userData= new ArrayList<UserData>();
// add data likewise in your list
userData.add(new UserData("name");
```

**3.** Inflate this list in ListView

```
YourAdapter adapter= new YourAdapter (context, userData);
listView.setAdatper(adapter);
```

Now, you can always access the list data through `userData`